# Intercept and re-write Entity Framework INSERT statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

**The tl;dr**

I'm using EF to insert items into an updateable view, rather than a table. EF isn't dealing well with the situation, but it's a simple fix if I can re-write the SQL just before it's sent to the database. Anyone know if there are any places I can inject some rewrite code?

**In Depth**

I have a view called `[VW_Item]` rather than a table called `[Item]`.

When I try an insert, Entity Framework generates SQL like this;

```
01 exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[vw_Item]([ItemName]) VALUES (@0)
02 SELECT [ItemId] FROM [dbo].[vw_Item]
03 WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ItemId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(256)',@0=N'my item name'
```

EF seems to work like this;

1. On line `01`, Insert the new record
2. On line `02`, Use `scope_identity()` to figure out the ID of the record you just inserted.

However, since I'm inserting into a view, and there's an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger involved, `scope_identity()` ends up being NULL, not the ID of my new record. EF gets confused and thinks that the insert failed.

I could easily rewrite the code like this;

```
01 exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[vw_Item]([ItemName]) VALUES (@0)
02 SELECT [ItemId] FROM [dbo].[vw_Item]
03 WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ItemId] = (select top(1) ItemId from [vw_Item])',N'@0 nvarchar(256)',@0=N'my item name'
```

So a small change at the end of line 03. However, I can't find a way to alter the INSERT statement sent to the server. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I think you could map insert to a stored procedure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model, change the mappings for your Item entity to use functions that you've added to the model (as stored procedures).

You then have complete control of the sql used to insert/update/delete your entities. 
A word of warning: if you alter one mapping you have to provide them all though - you can't have the auto-sql for update/delete and function mapping for insert.